# Onde colocar a anotação @Produces e @Consumes? No método ou na classe?

Tags: java, web-service, rest, restful

Estive estudando o funcionamento de APIs REST em Java e me deparei com duas didáticas diferentes. Em uma delas o professor colocava as anotações na definição da classe, desta maneira:

```
@Path("imoveis")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public class .....
```

e em outra didática o professor colocava as anotações especificamente em cima de cada método, desta maneira:

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public ......
```

Gostaria de saber qual a maneira mais correta de se declarar essas anotações, quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma delas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exemplo que você mostrou, os dois vão acabar resultando na mesma configuração.

A diferença de adoção deve ser relacionada exclusivamente à sua necessidade.

1. **Meu controller irá sempre consumir e retornar JSON**

Neste caso não faz sentido você colocar as anotações em cada método (lembre-se sempre do [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!)

2. **Meu controller irá consumir e retornar múltiplos formatos**

Nesta situação, você pode anotar os métodos, porque provavelmente você terá métodos específicos consumindo XML ou outro formato, métodos consumindo apenas JSON, e métodos consumindo vários formatos.

---

Hoje você não possui uma necessidade de retornar ou consumir vários/diferentes formatos, então faz sentido deixar apenas na classe. Amanhã caso você tenha XML como retorno e consumo (e a classe estiver anotada), você pode anotar apenas o método que irá tratar esta situação com XML e o resto da classe ainda irá tratar JSON (conforme anotado na classe).

De forma prática, o resultado é o mesmo, você deve considerar  a melhor estrutura do seu código e evitar repetições.

**Complemento:**

Conforme apontei no comentário para melhor entendimento, a idéia seria deixar as coisas comuns a maioria dos controladores nas anotações da classe, e então ir especializando nos métodos conforme a necessidade (devemos sempre considerar o DRY, deixando coisas comuns em apenas um lugar se possível)

Comment: No meu caso eu tinha alguns métodos que não consumiam nem retornavam dados, alguns métodos que apenas retornavam, e também tinha uns que consumiam e retornavam, por isso eu fiquei confuso.

Comment: @Eduardo Essa é a idéia mesmo, geralmente configurações que são mais utilizadas por todos os métodos costumam a ficar na classe, e os métodos especializam conforme a necessidade

Comment: aa sim, agora eu entendi.